# How important is MySQL location geographically?

Tags: mysql, cdn, scaling

I read that StackExchange uses two data centers to house all of their servers, both data centers are in the US. I'm in Ireland so I'm sure US servers are fine for me, but how can StackExchange load quickly for users in Australia if all the database servers are in the US?

I'd just like to ask, does this mean for services like MySQL, being geographically close to the server isn't as big of a deal for keeping page load times fast?

I know they use a CDN to speed up their page load time and they probably cache certain pages to speed things up, but even if I go to some really old, unpopular question I can't notice any slow-down.

Comment: Electrons are really, really fast in relation to the distances between places on the surface of the earth.  Photons are even faster (in fiber optic cables).  And StackExchange doesn't use MySQL, as far as I know.

Comment: I think they use MSSQL I thought all SQL products would be about the same speed. Could MSSQL be faster?

Comment: There are lot of other stuff than the database server that influence the speed of the page load at the end user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The location of the database server relative to the viewer is not the significant performance factor.  As a site visitor, you aren't talking to the database -- you're talking to a web application server, which is talking to the database.

Far more important, usually, is the location of the database server relative to the application server, because many applications require multiple queries and thus multiple round trips to the database in order to render a single page, and these round trips increase the time it takes for a page to be rendered.  When the database is physically proximate to the application tier, that time becomes negligible.

Speaking in general web terms, in a well-managed site like SE, with all the supporting assets in a CDN, the only delay that is relevant to you is the transit time required for that one big HTTP request/response necessary to render the page content.  The transit time is not negligible, because the speed of light is still finite, so round trip times to far-flung locales even on the best routes can easily be in the 200-300ms range... but if you only need to traverse it once, you still have a respectable response time.

A site that uses a lot of ajax to fetch additonal data would not fare so well with the web server so far away.  If such design were needed, you'd need geographically distributed web servers, with adjacent database replicas, and geo-routing in DNS to send read-only ajax requests to the nearest web server, which could query its local replica, get a quick response, and return a quick answer.

I once moved a MySQL server -- relative to the app server -- from being ~0.5 ms away to being ~25ms away.  The page load time on the site (which was already not optimal) increased from 2 sec to 10 sec.  The reason?  The app had been through many iterations over the years and made a lot of unnecessary requests to the database... if I remember right, even the simplest page required 13 different queries, most of which were fetching data that wasn't actually used (like fetching your score even for pages that didn't actually display your score). This inefficiency went undetected as long as the app and the db were very, very close.  But, again, this was about the distance between the web server and the database, not the database and the browser.

Stack Exchange has two data centers but at last check one of them is only a hot standby/failover site.  The main site does all the work under normal operations.  And, SE uses MSSQL, but that, too, is immaterial, because the fundamental phenomenon at work here is a law of physics.

Comment: Thanks for such an in-depth answer! You said the database should be close to the application server, if I had lots of applications servers designed to be close to the user but only one database server would I not just have the same problem of the database being too far away from whatever is querying it?

Comment: If you want app servers close to users, you'll want database read replicas adjacent to the app servers, so that as much db traffic as possible can use the replicas.  In MySQL, a replica opens a connection to the master, and holds it open.  The master feeds a continuous stream of changes to the replica as they occur, and the replica applies those changes to its local data set.  The protocol has no need for layer 7 acknowledgements, so the replication delay -- best case, with appropriate capacity hardware and stable connections -- can be less than the round trip time between the two servers.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps StackExchange uses several copies of databases (DB Slaves) geographically distributed across different regions of the world. That explains high speed of work even with unpopular SQL-requests.

Also between Australia and West Coast of United States, direct communication via an underwater cable is possible, which ensures a high speed of operation.